# How can I make a v-for loop inside a Bootstrap grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, loops, vue.js, v-for

I've got an array of JavaScript objects that I must place into cols, one for each col. I've made a grid and when I was using only HTML and CSS it didn't give any problem. Now that I started using Vue to do so, the cols appear one under another, instead of side by side as they should appear (and they appeared before).

This is what I have for now.

```
            <div id="app">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div v-for="product in products" class="producte">
                        <div class="imgdesc">
                            <img :src="product.urlimg" class="img-fluid"><br>
                            {{ product.desc }}<br>
                        </div>
                        <img v-if="product.cartell === 'new'" src="imgs/sign_new_offer.png" class="cartell">
                        <img v-if="product.cartell === 'offer'" src="imgs/sign_offer.png" class="cartell">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The only problem I have is that they appear one under another and they must be side by side on computer (it's a responsive website). I don't know how I can get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try the giving the display as flex for class 'col-3'

```
<div id="app">
                <div class="col-3" style="display: flex;">
                    <div v-for="product in products" class="producte">
                        <div class="imgdesc">
                            <img :src="product.urlimg" class="img-fluid"><br>
                            {{ product.desc }}<br>
                        </div>
                        <img v-if="product.cartell === 'new'" src="imgs/sign_new_offer.png" class="cartell">
                        <img v-if="product.cartell === 'offer'" src="imgs/sign_offer.png" class="cartell">
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Also Note that you have put one extra closing tag for div [] which has to be removed

Answer (score 0):

The `v-for` directive should be used when you use the `col-x` class :

```
     <div id="app" class="row">
                <div class="col-3" v-for="product in products" >
                    <div class="producte">
                        <div class="imgdesc">
                            <img :src="product.urlimg" class="img-fluid"><br>
                            {{ product.desc }}<br>
                        </div>
                        <img v-if="product.cartell === 'new'" src="imgs/sign_new_offer.png" class="cartell">
                        <img v-if="product.cartell === 'offer'" src="imgs/sign_offer.png" class="cartell">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```